# Parse.com cloud code schedule every n minutes

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

Can I run function on Parse cloud code that will send push notifications to users in order. For example send push to user1, after 5 min send push to user2, etc? I mean could I schedule or invoke some function after n minutes for example. Will be grateful for any help. Thanks

Comment: yes, you can, please refer to documentation, it is fairly easy to set up schedule for cloud code job , https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs-scheduling

Comment: oh. So I can write a job, and then schedule it from dash board with settings that allow run every 5 min forever? Or I should schedule it in dash board every 5 min by myself?

Comment: you can click in automated schedule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule background jobs. Create a job as you wish, for example:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("my_job", function(request, response) {
    response.success("Ran scheduled job.");
});
```

Deploy that to your Parse App and go to your *Cloud Code* dashboard, then click on *Scheduled Jobs*. From there, click on *Schedule a Job* and set up the first time it should be called and it's frequency. Simply save that and you are ready! :)

Comment: And could I change frequency or stop or begin again this Job from code, or only from dashboard?

Comment: You can change that in the dashboard only, as far as I know.