# Send notification to all devices every 30 minutes with cloud code

Tags: ios, parse-platform, background-process, parse-cloud-code

I try to send a notification to all iOS devices in order to allow the phone to make repetitive task in background.

I've used this topic to make a solution: [Parse.com cloud code schedule every n minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013565/parse-com-cloud-code-schedule-every-n-minutes) but it doesn't work well.

EDIT: Solved, right code for that is:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("BackgroundUpdate", function(request, response) {
  var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  pushQuery.equalTo('deviceType', 'ios'); //Target all iOS devices
  Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery, 
    data: {
      "content-available": 1
    }
  },{ useMasterKey: true }).then(function() {
    response.success("Push was sent");
  }, function(error) {
    response.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
  });
});
```

And my code in iOS is this one:

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"Remote Notification for background execution, userInfo is %@", userInfo);
    [self updateHistoric];
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

I want to run the "updateHistoric" function when I receive the notification and I would like to have the notification without showing it in the phone but first I was trying to see if the notification was receive that's why I put an alert on it.

Comment: What is the status of notification in Push tab ? What was the frequency of cloud code while saving it on server?

Comment: one more thing why you specifying  specific device token in cloud code if you are intended to send push notification to all ios devices?

Comment: In the server logs I have this message: Cloud Code not loaded:
 { [Error: Cannot find module './data/cloud/main'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
The frequency is 1 minute for testing. 
And the device token is specified for testing too, because I want to test with my device before implementing it for all.

Comment: I didn't mention that I don't use parse.com but back4app so I can't see Push tab I think (I didn't found it)

Comment: have you deployed your cloud code ? https://www.parse.com/apps/yourprojectNamee/cloud_code/jobs  shows the job listed if you have deployed your code.

Comment: ![Cloud code deployed](http://hpics.li/16fd0ab)
As you can see I put the main.js in the cloud folder of Parse.
In the scheduled jobs I put this thing : ![Schedule Job](http://hpics.li/e5971e4)